# No data received form USB device

Tags: usb, avr, uvc

I'm implementing USB web cam on top of Atmega32U4.

I think I managed to implement transactions on the control endpoint, more or less correctly, as all the descriptors are transited and device reports correctly in the system.

Issue is when I'm trying to send video data out of the device, as nothing seems to go through.

The way I implemented data transmission (according to section 22.14 of datasheet) is as follows:

```c
  while (len > 0) {
    while (1) {
      cli();
      _select_endpoint(VIDEO_STREAMING_ENDPOINT);
      if (bit_is_set(UEINTX, TXINI) && bit_is_set(UEINTX, FIFOCON))
        break;
      sei();
      _delay_ms(1);
    }
    _clear_TXINI();
    while (bit_is_set(UEINTX, RWAL) && len > 0) {
      UEDATX = *buff++;
      --len;
    }
    _clear_FIFOCON();
    sei();
  }
```

When debugging this I noticed that bank is filled with data during the first loop, but data is not transmitted to the host. It is looping forever in the TXINI,FIFOCON part. Nothing, except the control requests, is shown in the Wireshark. I'm not sure if I missconfigured something on the MCU registers, so it is not sending data to the host upon the request, or in the descriptors, status, etc, so host is not asking for data.

**What might have I messed up?**

#### `lsusb -v`

```
Bus 001 Device 077: ID 6431:deb2 majkrzak majkrzak
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        32
  idVendor           0x6431 
  idProduct          0xdeb2 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 majkrzak
  iProduct                1 majkrzak
  iSerial                 1 majkrzak
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x00a0
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          1 majkrzak
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               1 majkrzak
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              1 majkrzak
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.50
        wTotalLength       0x0028
        dwClockFrequency       16.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          2
        iTerminal               1 majkrzak
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x00000000
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          1
        bSourceID               1
        iTerminal               1 majkrzak
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              1 majkrzak
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            13
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  1 (INPUT_HEADER)
        bNumFormats                         1
        wTotalLength                   0x0055
        bEndpointAddress                 0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmInfo                              0
        bTerminalLink                       2
        bStillCaptureMethod                 0
        bTriggerSupport                     0
        bTriggerUsage                       0
        bControlSize                        0
        bmaControls( 0)                    27
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            27
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFormatIndex                        1
        bNumFrameDescriptors                1
        guidFormat                            {32595559-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71}
        bBitsPerPixel                       8
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  0
        bAspectRatioX                       1
        bAspectRatioY                       1
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 2 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
        bCopyProtect                        0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            38
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x02
          Still image unsupported
          Fixed frame-rate
        wWidth                             16
        wHeight                            16
        dwMinBitRate                   262144
        dwMaxBitRate                   262144
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize         768
        dwDefaultFrameInterval        1000000
        bFrameIntervalType                  0
        dwMinFrameInterval            1000000
        dwMaxFrameInterval            1000000
        dwFrameIntervalStep                 0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

#### edit

I'd made a simple script with `pyusb` which is pulling data from the endpoint and it works. Wireshark is showing the transactions, so it means that in the `uvcvideo` case data is not pulled at all. Definitely I messed up the descriptors then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why uvc driver is not pulling any data for the device, is that you set `dwMaxVideoFrameSize` and `dwMaxPayloadTransferSize` to `0`. Set it to value high enough for your case and it will work.